# list.h list_del() giving kernel paging error

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm trying to implement a kernel system call to remove the first element from a queue.  I'm getting a SEGKILL when debugging in gdb, with a line in kernel logs: BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ....

My struct for the queue is as follows:

```
typedef struct msgQueue
{
    long len;
    void *data;
    struct list_head queue;
} msgQueue;
```

As you can see, it contains the pointer to a block of data, the length in bytes of that data, and a list_head struct object from list.h.

I inialize an object of type msgQueue(above) with these lines:

```
myQueue = (struct msgQueue *) kmalloc(sizeof(struct msgQueue), GFP_KERNEL);
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&myQueue->queue);
```

I implemnent a write function that is wroking correctly.  The queue is not empty when I'm trying to delete from it.  Here's the initialization of the new queue that I'm addingn and the lines to add it:

Function header:

```
asmlinkage long sys_writeMsgQueue(const void __user *data, long len)
```

Other lines:

```
tempQueue = (struct msgQueue *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct list_head), GFP_KERNEL);
tempQueue->data = kmalloc((size_t)len, GFP_KERNEL);
tempQueue->len = len;

uncopiedBytes = __copy_from_user(tempQueue->data, data, len);
list_add_tail(&(tempQueue->queue), &(myQueue->queue));
```

I can't paste all of even just my read function, because this is for a coure that I'm taking.  But here is what I hope are the relevant parts:

```
asmlinkage long sys_readMsgQueue(void __user *data, long len)
{
    long uncopiedBytes;
    uncopiedBytes = __copy_to_user(myQueue, data, len);
    printk("REMOVING FROM QUEUE AND FREEING\n\n\n");
    list_del(&(myQueue->queue));
}
```

When I implement this basic functionality of this in a self contained c program in eclipse to try to debug it, it runs fine.  Granted, I have to adjust it for user-space code so all of the kernel specific stuff is removed/changed (malloc instead of kmalloc, no system call-specific syntax, etc).  I included list.h that I download so I'm using all of the same functions and such as far as list.h goes.

Does anything stand out at you that would cause the kernel paging error in my kernel logs?

Answer (score 1):

```
tempQueue = (struct msgQueue *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct list_head), GFP_KERNEL);
```

looks wrong; you probably want

```
tempQueue = kmalloc(sizeof *tempQueue, GFP_KERNEL);
```

Comment: oops, that double del was an accident.  fixed.